# Matplotlib savefig with eps doesn't draw grid lines in a projection plane on a 3d plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, eps

In Matplotlib, I want to draw grid lines in all projection planes on a 3d plot in a EPS file. 
I wrote the below code. 
The code works as desired on the figure window and the PNG file, but not on the EPS file. 
In the EPS file, grid lines aren't drawn into one of three projection planes. 
I pasted the created PNG file (top) and EPS file (down, I can't paste .eps in this page. Hence, I pasted the converted image. I uploaded the EPS file to [here (openload)](https://oload.download/f/s0AyiX11ryU/test.eps).). 
Is there any ways to fix this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.gca(projection='3d')
ax1.set_aspect("equal")
ax1.view_init(elev=30., azim=40)

fileid="test"
path="C:..."
fig1.savefig(path+fileid+".eps", dpi=300)
fig1.savefig(path+fileid+".png", dpi=300)
```

[image: PNG file] [image: EPS file]

Comment: You should put the EPS somewhere public and post a URL here. Most likely this is a problem with creating the EPS though and so not really an EPS programming question.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I uploaded the EPS file to [openload](https://oload.download/f/s0AyiX11ryU/test.eps).

Answer (score 3):

Well the EPS **does** draw the grid line. The problem is that it draws them the same colour as the flat fill for the plane.

If you open the EPS file with a text editor, and go to line 261 you will see:

```
0.900 setgray
gsave
288.863762 206.238981 m
165.545964 132.223634 l
158.321608 301.489923 l
288.311228 367.946472 l
gsave
fill
```

If you change the `0.900 setgray` to `0.25 setgray` then render the EPS you will see that the plane is drawn in a much darker shade of gray, and the grid lines are now easily visible.

I have no idea if that's something you can change in matplotlib, but that's where the gray values are being generated, there's nothing wrong with the EPS. From the PNG you created directly, it 'looks like' the gray values being selected for the planes are too dark and that's where your problem lies.

As an experiment I tried changing the 3 gray values used to draw the planes from 0.950, 0.900 and 0.925 to 0.975, 0.945 and 0.960 and the results looked closer to the image you posted.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great help! I hope matplotlib fix this problem fundamentally.

Comment: If you encounter a bug in matplotlib you may report it at [the issue tracker](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues).